# Compiler-error while performing type-casting in Java

Tags: java, casting

Let's see the following expressions in Java.

```
int temp = -254;
Integer temp2 = (Integer) temp;        // compiles because of autoboxing

Integer temp3 = (Integer) -254;       // doesn't compile - illegal start of type.
Integer temp4 = (Integer) 10-254;     // compiles

Integer temp5 = (Integer) (int) -254; // compiles
Integer temp6 = -254;                 // compiles
Integer temp7 = (int) -254;           // compiles
```

In the above expressions, why are these expressions `(Integer) 10-254` and `(int) -254` valid whereas the expression `(Integer) -254` doesn't compile even though the constant `-254` can perfectly be evaluated to `Integer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting edge case, the compiler attempts to perform integer subtraction on the `Integer` class and an `int` literal (254).

Note that the following compiles and is more explicit:

```
    Integer temp3 = (Integer)(-254)
```

Answer (score 3):

More specifically, this is in accordance with the [section 15.16 of the JLS 3rd edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.16):

> A cast expression converts, at run time, a value of one numeric type
>   to a similar value of another numeric type; or confirms, at compile
>   time, that the type of an expression is boolean; or checks, at run
>   time, that a reference value refers to an object whose class is
>   compatible with a specified reference type.
>
> CastExpression:
>           ( PrimitiveType Dimsopt ) UnaryExpression
>           **( ReferenceType ) UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus**